# Navigating Nested Array of Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

If you have an array containing multiple arrays like this:
time_dhm = [array([ 1,  3, 18]), array([ 1,  3, 18]), array([ 1,  3, 18])]

For context, those are days/hours/minutes. I want to convert the whole thing to minutes.

How would I navigate each index on every nested arrays simultaneous so I can multiply the integer 24 or 60 or 24 and 60 and get the sum of the whole nested array when all are converted to minutes.

I tried using for loops but it multiplies everything by 24 including the ones that shouldn't be multiplied by 24. (I'm testing multiplying 24 to the first indices)

Edit: The first comment gave me an idea and I got it.

```
for i in range(0, 4xxx):
time_dhm[i][0] = time_dhm[i][0]*24*60
time_dhm[i][1] = time_dhm[i][1]*60
time_dhm[i] = sum(time_dhm[i])
```

It's similar to the second answer but I really had to use for loop because the quantity of the nested arrays I'm working with is more than 4000.

Comment: If you don't show your code, no one can tell you what you did wrong. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: hello @Julien, my bad, as I really didn't have any idea earlier. I forgot basic navigation of indices but the first comment gave me an idea. I got the code running now. Do I add it up as comment or edit the post?

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I want to convert the whole thing to minutes. ..."*

Try the following.

```py
time_dhm = [sum([x[0] * 1440, x[1] * 60, x[2]]) for x in time_dhm]
```

Output

```
[1638, 1638, 1638]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, I like the solution and it's similar to the one I arrived it but different because I need a for loop as the quantity of the actual nested array I have is more than 4000.

Comment: May I ask how do I make the question "answered"?

Comment: @GenesisPineda, no problem.  To mark it as "answered", there is a check-mark icon, below the voting arrows, for this answer. Selecting it should turn it green, signifying it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need to iterate over each sub-array in your time_dhm array and then get days, hours and minutes with their corresponding indexes "0" for days, "1" for hours and "2" for minutes. Then just do the math.

Eg.

```
time_dhm = [array([1, 3, 18]), array([1, 3, 18]), array([1, 3, 18])]

total_minutes = 0
for time in time_dhm:
    minutes = time[0] * 24 * 60 + time[1] * 60 + time[2]
    total_minutes += minutes

print("Total minutes:", total_minutes)
```

Comment: Hello, I think you misunderstood what I wanted for the solution. Every array should still be separated such that if you have 3 arrays containing days/hours/minutes, the result would be 3 arrays containing the total minutes for each array.